# how to add tomcat to tomcat.service for systemctl startup

Tags: centos, tomcat

I want to write a systemctl deamon for my tomcat installation so I can start tomcat using below command

`systemctl start tomcat`.

Right now I am using the `startup.sh` script to start the Tomcat server. How do I get it managed by systemctl?

Comment: `systemctl enable tomcat`, should change your system so that tomcat should start after every reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Create a template service unit file at /etc/systemd/system/tomcat@.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat - instance %i
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

WorkingDirectory=/var/tomcat/%i

Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom"

Environment="CATALINA_PID=/var/tomcat/%i/run/tomcat.pid"
Environment="CATALINA_BASE=/var/tomcat/%i/"
Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/"
Environment="CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

#RestartSec=10
#Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable tomcat@foo.service
systemctl start tomcat@foo.service
```

Answer (score 0):

To start up your Tomcat installation using systemctl, you'll need to create a systemd service unit file for Tomcat. Here's how you can do it:

**Create a systemd Service Unit File:**

Open a terminal and navigate to the systemd service directory:
`cd /etc/systemd/system`
Create a new service unit file for Tomcat. You can name it tomcat.service:
`sudo nano tomcat.service`
Add the following content to the tomcat.service file:

```
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Adjust the Environment variables and paths (CATALINA_PID, CATALINA_HOME, CATALINA_BASE) according to your Tomcat installation directory.

**Reload systemd Manager Configuration:**

After creating the service unit file, you need to reload the systemd manager configuration to make systemd aware of the new service:
`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

**Enable the Service:**

Enable the Tomcat service to start automatically on system boot:
`sudo systemctl enable tomcat`

**Start the Service:**

You can now start the Tomcat service using systemctl:
`sudo systemctl start tomcat`

**Check Status:**

You can check the status of the Tomcat service to ensure it's running:
`sudo systemctl status tomcat`

With these steps, you should be able to start up your Tomcat installation using systemctl just like any other systemd-managed service.